# IOS objective-C instance vars -- what's the difference

Tags: objective-c, ios

What is the difference between declaring variables in the interface section vs. in the implementation section outside of a method.

Comment: You should show an example of what you mean by outside.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you mean in the ivar block in the implementation, as in

```
@implementation MyClass {
    id someIvar;
}
// methods go here
@end
```

If so, then the only difference is visibility to other code. At runtime, the ivar will be indistinguishable from one declared in the `@interface` section. However, code outside the class can see ivars declared in `@interfaces`, and unless those ivars are marked with `@protected` or `@private`, then the other classes can reach in and twiddle the ivars. But ivars declared in the `@implementation` are not even visible to code outside, so they cannot touch the ivars.

For the most part, this is just a code cleanliness issue. Nothing should go in the header file unless it's meant to be public. So why put ivars there?

As Josh Caswell noted, ivars declared in this fashion require a recent version of Clang.

---

The alternative interpretation of your question is you have code like

```
@implementation MyClass

- (void)someMethod { /* ... */ }

NSString *var;

- (void)otherMethod { /* ... */ }
@end
```

If this is what you meant, then the answer is, don't do that. In this code snippet we've declared a global variable named `var` rather than an instance variable. The location of the variable inside the `@implementation` block is irrelevant, it's exactly identical to a global variable in C (because that's what it is).

Comment: I think it should be noted that ivars in the implementation block are a relatively new feature; this won't compile under GCC or (AFAICT) Clang < 2.

Comment: Even if those ivars are marked with protected or private, any code can reach in and twiddle the ivars. The compiler will only give a warning

Answer (score 2):

A variable declared in the `@interface` is an *instance* variable. In more recent compilers instance variables can also be declared in a block in the `@implementation` in a similar way to doing so in the `@interface` - this effects their *visibility* but not their *lifetime*.

A variable declared "outside of a method" in the implementation, as in:

```
@implementation

static int CallCount = 0;
```

is the closest thing Objective-C has to a *class* variable - a variable which all instances of a class share, as opposed to *instance* variables where each object instance has its own variable.

Such a variable has execution lifetime - it exists throughout a single execution of the whole application - just as typical class variables do in other languages. (The lifetime of instance variables is that of the object instance they belong to.)

The use of `static` further limits the visibility (not its lifetime) of the variable name to just the file containing the declaration - like a private class variable in other languages. Note that, unlike most languages class variables, variables declared in an `@implementation` **without** a `static` qualifier are added to the global namespace and thus increase the opportunities for name collisions - this is why they are not *real* class variables.

Such class variables are often initialized using the class method `+ initialize`, just as instance variables are initialized using the instance method `- init`.

Answer (score 1):

Declaring them in a class extension is often used in attempt to hide the instance variables and associated accessors from the client. Neither approach truly hides them, but hiding them is usually an improvement, and is available only if all compilers you need support it.

Comment: An "anonymous category" is actually called a class extension.

Comment: @Kevin right - i knew that. thanks for spotting it. (off to make a coffee...)